# plot different arrays together (time sincronization) in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have arrays(vectors(1...k)) with different dimensions each
`a[1,4], b[1,7], c[1,9]`
that contain indexes of values I'd like to plot.

I need to plot all this values on one plot - so if array `a` represents values in first 4 seconds and `b` represents it in next 7 second - then I need firstly draw `a` values at 1-4 second interval (this I have done) ) but I need that the plot for `b` values will start also from 1 second (and to 7) on the same plot (I am using hold on but still could not synchronize time) and same for `c`..

I have wrote already a loop for this arrays "parsing" and it works - the problem is synchronization of times

```
dataCell ; % it is inited in this step same is for timeval and dataArr (this two has the same dimensions)
figure  % new picture)
hold on % on the same plot
for l=1:length(data) % for all cells
pointer=dataCell{1,l}; % point to cell element (array)
for n =1: length(pointer) %loop for all inner elements
 plot(timeval(pointer(n)),dataArr(pointer(n)),'b') % <- this is plots OK but no any synchronization
end
end
```

Comment: could you include some code?

Comment: I have provide my code

Comment: are `timeval` and `dataArr` matrices? how do you initialize `dataCell`? what's `data`?

Comment: timeval is array [1..n] and dataArr also array [1..n]. dataCell contains arrays of selected indices from 1 to n. like [2 ,3,4] [5,6] and so on

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

Your initial vectors:

```
a = rand(1,4);
b = rand(1,7);
c = rand(1,9);
timestamp = 0:9;

hold all
plot(timestamp(1:numel(a)),a)
plot(timestamp(1:numel(b)),b)
plot(timestamp(1:numel(c)),c)
```

*Or*, if I misunderstood:

```
d = [a, b(numel(a)+1:end), c(numel(b)+1:end)];
plot(timestamp,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

you say

> if array `a` represents values in first 4 seconds and `b` represents it in next 7 second - then I need firstly draw `a` values at 1-4 second interval (this I have done) ) but I need that the plot for `b` values will start also from 1 second (and to 7) on the same plot

and

> timeval is array [1..n] and dataArr also array [1..n]. dataCell contains arrays of selected indices from 1 to n. like [2 ,3,4] [5,6] and so on

but you implemented

```
plot(timeval(pointer(n)),dataArr(pointer(n)),'b')
```

this will plot `a` at timestamps `[2,3,4]` and `b` at timestamps `[5,6]`.

If I interpret correctly your request, what you actually need is

```
plot(timeval(n),dataArr(pointer(n)),'b')
```